# for loop -- ununderstandable behavior

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have have these `for` loops:

```
for ($x = 0; $x<2;$x++){

$allproducts = array();
for ($y = 0; $y<105;$y++) {   //<<<<<<<<<<<<< this (105) is the number I mean
    $allproducts[] = 'test'.$y;
}

echo "<pre>";
echo "allproducts 0 -- ";

var_dump($allproducts);

echo "</pre>";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($allproducts); $i++) {


    $result = array_slice($allproducts, 0, 20);

    echo "<pre>";
    echo "result --  ";
    var_dump($result);
    echo "</pre>";


    $allproducts = (array_diff($allproducts, $result));

    echo "<pre>";
    echo "allproducts 1 -- ";
    var_dump($allproducts);
    echo "</pre>";
}}
```

---

In real code (here:)

```
for ($x = 0; $x<1;){
    $allproducts = array();
    $abfrage = "SELECT sku FROM skulist";
    if ($result = $sql->query($abfrage))
    {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $allproducts[] = $row['sku'];
        }
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($allproducts); ++$i) {
        $result = array_slice($allproducts, 0, 20);
        $allproducts = (array_diff($allproducts, $result));

//.... more code 

}}
```

...I take data from DB instead of this for loop:

```
$allproducts = array();
for ($y = 0; $y<105;$y++) {   //<<<<<<<<<<<<< this (105) is the number I mean
    $allproducts[] = 'test'.$y;
}
```

but changed it to show/ for easier reconstruction.

---

**The behavior is the same:**

When I have 105 entries in my array, I don't get an empty array output for

```
echo "allproducts 1 -- ";
var_dump($allproducts);
```

which is the desired behavior.

When I change `105` to (eg.) `65`, it outputs an empty arrays

```
allproducts 1 -- array(0)
```

at the end of the second nested loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($allproducts); $i++) {
```

Now I have ***three problems***:

- why does this happen? I don't get the difference
- how can I achieve, that there is no empty array at the end? (stops my programs work)
- I need 20 values in every $result array

Comment: are you sure, when you get from the database, the value is ok?

Comment: You need to consider `foreach` instead of `for` for iterating over an array

Comment: Yes, the values are definately ok when coming from DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($allproducts); $i++) {
    // ...
    $allproducts = (array_diff($allproducts, $result));
```

You are *changing* your `$allproducts` array while going through it! How can you expect it to work reliably then?

Instead, try:

```
foreach( $allproducts as $i => $product)
```

Although I must admit I'm not sure what you're trying to do.